# EJB 3.1 problems

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I try to deploy a jboss5 bean project bundle on a jboss7 server. An other developer already made some changes that the code can work on jboss7, like to place a jboss-deployment-structure.xml into the project.

I created two beans, one in project A (BeanA) and one in project B (BeanB).
BeanA has to lookup for BeanB. I always get "No EJB found with interface of type 'de.foo.soa.foobar.al.BeanB' for binding de.foo.soa.foobar.ba.ProjectB/BeanB.

Bean B:

```
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.ejb.LocalBean;

    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class NumSrvLocalBean {

        public String testNumSrv() {
            return "numsrv works";
        }
    }
```

Bean A does:

```
@EJB private NumSrvLocalBean numSrvLocalBean;
private String numSrvLocalBean_path = "java:module/NumSrvLocalBean!de.foo.soa.foobar.al.NumSrvLocalBean";
ctx = new InitialContext();
numSrvLocalBean = (NumSrvLocalBean) ctx.lookup(numSrvLocalBean_path);
```

I also added the right dependency to the jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
    <module name="deployment.ProjectB.jar" export="true"/>
```

So evertything is fine for my understanding but I always get this exception. I created my own project, lets call it project X. There I can lookup for any Bean I want to from all other projects (about 15). I cant inject in project A any bean outside from project A. But I can inject beans inside the project. So there must be something that blocks the beans inside the project.

I've got this files in project A:

- jboss.xml
- jboss-deployment-structure.xml
- MANIFEST.MF (standard, not filled)
- persistence.xml
- seam.properties
- ProjectA.properties (contains an wsdlUrl because this project was also configured as XML-RPC project)

I look forward four your ideas,

greetings.

Comment: I'm not sure here, but AFAIK `java:module` would mean a lookup in the _current_ module, that's why you can lookup BeanC from BeanA. You'd need to add the module name to the lookup path. Have a look at the management console (port 9990 by default) and check the bound JNDI paths.

Comment: You'r right, but I also tested it with 'global:..'.
Thats the result:
15:32:38,953 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ProjectA/ProjectA!de.foo.soa.foobar.ba.BeanA -- service jboss.naming.context.java.global.ProjectA."BeanA!de.foo.soa.foobar.ba.BeanA"

15:32:38,955 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5)  at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
(and more lines).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I wont see anything in the management console because there is nothing deployed cause of the error.

Comment: That's true but maybe you can try and deploy project B alone or temporarily remove the lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using EJB(mappedName="java:global/....").
I already tried EJB(mappedName=className.JNDI_NAME) but this didnt worked. We used Interfaces in JBoss 5, where we defined the JNDI name like

```
@Local
public interface ClassNameLocal extends ClassNameInterface {

    /** Name im JNDI (Java Naming and Directory Interface) */
    public final static String JNDI_NAME = "foo/bar/and/so/on/ClassName/local";

}
```

This seems not to work anymore. I needed to use the full path.